# Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...) with Redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-form

I deleted my node_modules folder and reinstalled everything from scratch (as one does). Now when I hit my `/profile` route (using ReactRouter) I get the following error:

```
invariant.js?7ab6:38Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): 
Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component
that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple
copies of React loaded (details: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).
```

I have in the render method of my component:

```
<ProfileFormConnected initialValues={currentUser && { university_name: currentUser.university_name }} updateCurrentUser={ ::this.props.updateCurrentUser } />
```

If I remove that line, the problem is solved.
The implementation of `ProfileFormConnected` is practically straight from the `redux-form` docs:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  const requiredFields = [ 'university_name' ]
  requiredFields.forEach(field => {
    if (!values[ field ]) {
      errors[ field ] = 'Required'
    }
  })
  return errors
}

const renderTextField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, ...custom }) => (
    <TextField hintText={label}
      floatingLabelText={label}
      errorText={touched && error}
      {...input}
      {...custom}
    />
)

class ProfileForm extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit,
      pristine,
      reset,
      submitting,
      updateCurrentUser
    } = this.props

    return (
      <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(updateCurrentUser) }>
        <Field name="university_name" component={renderTextField} label="University Name" />
        <div>
          <RaisedButton type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting} label="Save" />
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }

}

const ProfileFormConnected = reduxForm({
  form: 'profile',
  validate
})(ProfileForm);

export default ProfileFormConnected
```

The page linked to in the error message suggests that sometimes you can have multiple copies of React but if I am interpreting this output correctly, that doesn't seem to be the case here:

```
npm ls | grep react
electron-react-boilerplate@0.10.0 /home/mike/projects/upundit/upundit-desktop
│ ├── react-addons-css-transition-group@15.4.1
├─┬ babel-preset-react@6.16.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name@6.8.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx@6.8.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-helper-builder-react-jsx@6.18.0
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@6.11.0
│ └── babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@6.9.0
├─┬ babel-preset-react-optimize@1.0.1
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements@6.9.1
│ ├── babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements@6.8.0
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-pure-class-to-function@1.0.1
│ │ └── babel-helper-is-react-class@1.0.0
│ └── babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types@0.2.11
├── eslint-plugin-react@6.8.0
│ ├── react-addons-create-fragment@15.4.1
│ ├── react-addons-transition-group@15.4.1
│ ├─┬ react-event-listener@0.4.0
│ │ └── react-addons-shallow-compare@15.4.1
├─┬ react@15.4.1
├── react-addons-test-utils@15.4.1
├─┬ react-apollo@0.5.16
│ ├── hoist-non-react-statics@1.2.0
├─┬ react-dom@15.4.1
├─┬ react-electron-webview@1.0.7
├─┬ react-hot-loader@3.0.0-beta.6
│ ├── react-deep-force-update@2.0.1
│ ├─┬ react-proxy@3.0.0-alpha.1
│ ├─┬ redbox-react@1.3.3
├─┬ react-redux@4.4.6
├─┬ react-router@3.0.0
├── react-router-redux@4.0.7
├─┬ react-tap-event-plugin@2.0.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint-plugin-import@^1.16.0, required by eslint-config-airbnb@12.0.0
npm ERR! extraneous: node-pre-gyp@0.6.32 /home/mike/projects/upundit/upundit-desktop/node_modules/node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint-plugin-import@^1.16.0, required by eslint-config-airbnb-base@8.0.0
```

Can anyone see what is causing that invariant violation?

Answer (score -1):

Check for refs that are using a string.

I had a similar issue and was able to resolve it by not using string refs.

Good:

```
 <input ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input }} />
```

Bad:

```
 <input ref="textInput" />
```

Check out the docs here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

They actually say don't do that:

"If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to be removed in one of the future releases. If you're currently using this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern instead."